# GPS Altitude uncertainty and postional uncertainty in Lat/Long

Tags: gps, latitude-longitude, altitude

I'm working on flight sensors for a project and I'm supposed to model GPS device noise. I looked a lot for it online and could not get a convincing answer.

I need the uncertainties of altitude and Lat/Long measurements from an **aviation grade GPS device** such as a GARMIN GTN 750. By uncertainty I mean + or - certain metres for altitude and + or - certain degrees for Lat/Long.

I found just one web page mentioning the vertical uncertainty as 10m but again there was no reference attached to it and nothing for Lat/Long.

Comment: what receiver and corrections are you using? Positional uncertainty is going to be directly based on this.

Comment: There is no real receiver. All these are for simulation purposes only and I'm in dire need of realistic values of uncertainties for the GPS altitude and GPS Lat/Long.

Comment: You should probably pick a unit and simulate to the manufactures specs.  What your asking is going to be answered in whatever receivers manual you choice.

Comment: I did check up on that and I came to know that GARMIN products are used for a lot of aviation purposes and in their website, they don't have this information in the product specification section.

Comment: add the unit to the question I'm sure someone here can answer it.

Comment: It boils down to chipset see some examples http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/GPS_Chipset

Comment: My assumed update rate is 10 Hz. So can I just pick a value of 3m accuracy (The corresponding accuracy in lat/long)? Also, it says nothing about the accuracy of altitude.

Comment: Inertial navigation systems like https://www.applanix.com/ are often used to remove noise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the spec sheet of the Garmin GTN receiver the accuracy is 1m.

Since you are simulating I would use the FAA's range of 1.5 horizontal and vertical:

> The WAAS message improves the accuracy, availability and integrity of
>   GPS-derived position information. Using WAAS, GPS signal accuracy is
>   improved from 20 meters to approximately 1.5 – 2 meters in both the
>   horizontal and vertical dimensions

https://www.faa.gov/news/fact_sheets/news_story.cfm?newsId=14974

http://www8.garmin.com/aviation/pdfs/GTN_series_brochure.pdf

Comment: But is the 1m accuracy is for position or altitude?